# how to load c# application in start up of computer or any user log in. And in a side tray

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, registrykey

I am working on a c# application in which i want to load the application as windows start up or as user log in. I am working on Windows & with VS2010.
I am writing following code to use registry key but it gives me error of access denied.

```
    RegistrySecurity RS = new RegistrySecurity();
    RS.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(Environment.UserName.ToString(),RegistryRights.WriteKey | RegistryRights.ReadKey | RegistryRights.Delete | RegistryRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
    RegistryKey reg = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVer­sion\\Run",RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree,RS);
    reg.SetAccessControl(RS);
    reg.SetValue("Pratham", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
```

I don't have any idea about running app in side tray please help me with it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please explain what you mean with side tray.

Comment: @CrashproofCode with side tray i mean the system tray which is there on the left side of clock on task bar.

Comment: Take a look at System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon.

Comment: @JamesR. is it for system tray?

Comment: Yes.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
String programName = "Test Name";
String programPath = "C:\\test.exe";

Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", programName, programPath);
```

The reason you get access denied though is that you might need to run the program as administrator.

To add your program to the "side tray" add a NotifyIcon to your form from the toolbox or simply use:

```
NotifyIcon icon = new NotifyIcon();
```

Comment: but is the current user  key fine? i mean to say that it should work for all user.
how to write to registries using program coding because the app will be installed on different user machines.

Comment: Sorry, I changed it now. It should be HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Comment: how to run program as administrator when debugging it?
and also when every user installs it on their machine and it needs to be started as their system start up how will be implemented?